# Do the new ribbons (Gun Master, Tank Superiority, and Domination) count toward Decorated?

Tags: achievements, battlefield-3

I haven't yet unlocked the "Decorated" achievement for Battlefield 3 on the Xbox 360.

Description:

> Obtain one of each ribbon in the game

This achievement was part of the original game.  The Armored Kill (September) update has added 3 new ribbons to the awards section of Battlelog, one each for winning a round of Gun Master, Conquest Domination and Tank Superiority.  This bring the total number of unique ribbons up from 45 to 48.

Do I now need to win the 3 new ribbons in addition to the remaining ribbons from the original game to unlock the achievement, or is it based solely on the original 45 ribbons?

Comment: I am going to take a guess and say only the initial 45 will count. As I have unlocked the achievement and I could see it being unfair to change the requirements for those who have not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment is based only upon the initial 45 ribbons. Unless they make a future update to the achievement - something I haven't heard of before - you only need to obtain the initial 45 ribbons.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, do you have a verified source on it, or are you just guessing? I think you're probably correct, but would like to verify it first before accepting.

Comment: Personal experience. I have no source, other than other people saying the same thing unfortunately. AFAIK, there is no "official" source. You could tweet at the Battlefield 3 account and see if you get a response on it.

Comment: Confirmed. I just unlocked my final ribbon from the original 45 (Squad Deathmatch) and the achievement popped, even though I still haven't won the new "Gunmaster Winner" ribbon.